# How to create an array of regex matches

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to create the following array:

```
@domains = ("lmcaster.espn.go.com", "gomailfileus.go.com");
```

I was experimenting with using regex but I'm not successful in populating the array. I'm pretty sure my regex part is messed up. Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dns_output = <<END;
199.181.132.138  lmcaster.espn.go.com (300)
199.181.132.133  gomailfileus.go.com (300)
END

my @domains = ($dns_output =~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s([[:graph:]])\s[[:graph:]]/);

for my $d (@domains) {
        print "Domain: $d\n";
}
```

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `/g` modifier, first, and to add `+` quantifier so the whole domain (and not only its first symbol) would be captured, second.

```
my @domains = $dns_output =~ /(?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+\s*([[:graph:]]+)/g;
```

I'd compressed IP grouping as well here, and have added `*` quantifier to `\s` separating the domain.

Comment: Works perfectly. I also learned how to reduce code, use + and of course /g.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
my @domains = $dns_output =~ /^ \d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+ \s+ (\S+) /xmg;
```

Comment: Oh @mpapec, this is one of those answers where you provide some code, but provide no rationale or explanation for your changes. Some aspects are purely stylistic (`[.]` instead of `\.`; `/x`). Some changes modify the meaning in probably irrelevant ways (anchoring at start of line, `\d` matches more characters than `[0-9]`, `\S` matches more than `[[:graph:]]`). Finally, only adding `/g` and the `+` operator were relevant.

Comment: @amon tnx for feedback; input data looks plain/simple so I chose more liberal approach.